# How to check if PHP rand() has randomly generated all the possible unique numbers by randomly generating numbers

Tags: php, random, numbers, unique

I want to make sure that PHP rand() function has randomly generated all the possible **unique** numbers between the range given.

for example, this function **rand(0,9)** can generate **unique** numbers only 10 times right. ex: (randomly: 1,10,4,3,7,9,0,5,8,2,6)-(no duplication). So how do i determine that this rand() function has generated its all possible unique numbers?

Comment: I would have thought that just generating a random number MAY generate the same number more than once.  Otherwise it's not random.

Comment: You can't do that using rand() function. But you can try: <?php
echo uniqid();
?>

Comment: @MahfuzShishir How to determine that through unique() function?
can you show me an example?

Comment: You should read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php It does not guarantee you. It depends on your system.

Comment: if u want to generate unique numbers always then their is different approach... but why u want to do that...? i mean what exactly you are trying to do... ?

Comment: Do you really want to shuffle of a set of numbers randomly?  If so then have a look at the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write an algorithm. A very inefficient example would be:

```
$already_generated = array();
while(count($already_generated) < 10) {
    $rand_val = rand(0,9);
    if(!in_array($rand_val)) {
        $already_generated[] = $rand_val;
    }
}
```

This algorithm is obviously very inefficient but should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to produce a list of numbers in random order from 0 to n, this code should do that.

It starts with a list of numbers 0 to `$max` and then each time it picks one of the numbers, adds it to the output list and then removes it from the input set.  Then repeats while there are numbers left.

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$max = 9;
$list = range(0, $max);

$output = array();
while ( count($list) > 0 )  {
    $rnd = rand(0,count($list)-1);
    $output[] = $list[$rnd];
    unset($list[$rnd]);
    $list = array_values($list);
}

print_r($output);
```